# Ajax TabContainer causing browser to close automatically

Tags: asp.net, browser, tabcontainer

I am trying to fix an issue. I have an ASP.NET Ajax's TabContainer on the page. And each tab there  is a gridview control that gets binded onload. However for some reason the browser gets closed automatically after the page renders. If I remove the TabContainer then it works fine.
       I think the binding code will no way effect the browser to close bacause no where in my code I am registering any Script block.

Also one notable thing is this happens only in IE 8. It works fine in firefox and other browsers.

I don't know if anyone encountered a similar issue before.

Thanks...

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps IE is crashing because of a rendering bug? Have you tried googling for known issues?

Comment: I'm sure what Xian said is true. Because javascript won't be able to close the window without a confirmation box being popped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although its late to respond I figured out the problem some time ago. The problem was that the page that launched the tabContainer page had an update panel and that was causing the issue and my problem was fixed after I removed the Update panel from the parent page.

Thanks for your suggestions guys.